# Magento 1.9.2 and php7 - image upload error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, fatal-error, php-7

I'm just testing Magento 1.9.2 with Php 7. All seemed to work, but suddenly I tried to upload image for the product. I got error like below:

```
Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /home/admin/domains/store.com/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php:259
Stack trace:
#0 /home/admin/domains/store.com/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php(180): Varien_File_Uploader-&gt;_validateFile()
#1 /home/admin/domains/store.com/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php(46): Varien_File_Uploader-&gt;save('/home/admin/dom...')
#2 /home/admin/domains/store.com/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_GalleryController-&gt;uploadAction()
#3 /home/admin/domains/store.com/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action-&gt;dispatch('upload')
#4 /home/admin/domains/store.com/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard-&gt;match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller in <b>/home/admin/domains/store.com/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

Anybody know how to fix it?

Function affected in upload.php at line around 259

```
protected function _validateFile()
    {
        if ($this->_fileExists === false) {
            return;
        }

        //is file extension allowed
        if (!$this->checkAllowedExtension($this->getFileExtension())) {
            throw new Exception('Disallowed file type.');
        }
        //run validate callbacks
        foreach ($this->_validateCallbacks as $params) {
            if (is_object($params['object']) && method_exists($params['object'], $params['method'])) {
                $params['object']->$params['method']($this->_file['tmp_name']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.incompatible.php
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax

Due to uniform variable syntax the code is now interpreted strictly from left to right.

The line

```
$params['object']->$params['method']($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

should be

```
$params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

You can find a overview of all files to edit in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/105604/37536).

Comment: Cool, works 100% I hope Magento 1.9.2 doesn't have any other php 7 incompatibility. Thanks for help!

Comment: this code work for me magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: This solution has all the files you'll need to edit for a good PHP7 performance: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/105604/37536

Comment: Awesome...It's working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to the answers above, don't forget to check the file:

\includes\src\Varien_File_Uploader.php on line 259

**Replace**

```
$params['object']->$params['method']($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

**with**

```
$params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: simply re-compile rather than edit these temp files?