# magento install gets to a 500 error

Tags: error, installation, php-7

I am facing a issue while trying to install magento.

I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:555
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#1 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Install/controllers/WizardController.php(120): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#2 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Install_WizardController->beginAction()
#3 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('begin')
#4 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5  /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php(682): Mage_Core_Model_App- in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 555
```

#### Configuration details:

- OS: ubuntu 15.10
- Apache: 2.4.18
- php: 7.0.2
- mysql: 5.7.10

Comment: which Magento version?

Answer (score 12):

Magento 1.x is not fully compatible with PHP 7, see: [Is Magento ready for PHP 7?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74008/is-magento-ready-for-php-7/80912#80912)

This specific bug can be fixed, by overriding `Mage_Core_Model_Layout` and change line 555 from:

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback[1]();
```

to

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
```