# Magento 1.9.1 - suggestion needed for PHP 7 version and extension compatibility

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, php-7

Before someone put it as duplicate post, i found this link :

[Is Magento ready for PHP 7?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74008/is-magento-ready-for-php-7)

but i want to know about **advantages of php 7 over php 5.6 & extensions issues**.

we set up magento site in php 5.6 version.

as PHP 7 is ready, now we want to go for PHP 7.

we want to know is there any advantages and disadvantages of upgrading to php 7 version?

also we used lot of extensions in our site, will it affects on our extensions also ?

Comment: All your queries is already answered in linked post, I suggest you read all the answer first.

Comment: can you please tell advantages of going for php 7 and also any problems for extensions features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are none advantages, or very little. there is no gain as many of you thinking like "200% faster than php55", lol its not. probably in some lab tests with specific test cases php7 is better than php5, but in real life its just an another version of php.

the pages like this http://www.zend.com/en/resources/php7_infographic  make me laugh like mad... especially they trying to compare php7 to hhvm 3.7, this is what i call "stupid marketing". not sure why they use it.
the same as comparing any full page cache to Varnish, and saying that Varnish is slower.

this is all about your application design. if you have bad code and slow page loading time, it will be the same.

also ioncube not working with php7. not sure why people using it in magento...

Comment: nice, Really impressive. than we will think about going for php 7.

Comment: Did you do any tests that back up your opinion?

Comment: Switching from PHP 5.5 to PHP 7 on my Windows development computer decreased average page load times from 2 seconds to 0.5 seconds.  This is with Magento's caching disabled and no optimizations enabled for PHP.  However, Magento 1.9 has some issues with PHP 7.

Answer (score 2):

It's relatively easy to modify magento to run support PHP7. **However many extensions are still not PHP7 compatible** so you're largely on your own.