# Magento 1 on Nginx with PHP 7 - 500 Error - Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string Layout.php:555 Stack trace

Tags: magento2, magento-1, migration

Throwing error while moving Magento 1 website on php 7 configured server.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
>   /home/mcs/html/sitemain/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:555
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/mcs/html/sitemain/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() #1
>   /home/mcs/html/sitemain/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout() #2
>   /home/mcs/html/sitemain/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController),
>   'no-route') #3
>   /home/mcs/html/sitemain/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController),
>   'no-route') #4
>   /home/mcs/html/sitemain/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>   Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction() #5
>   /home/mcs/html/sitemain/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute') #6
>   /home/mcs/html/sitem in
>   /home/mcs/html/sitemain/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php
>   on line 555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 1.9 on PHP 7 is bit tricky to install because php 7 fully does not support Magento 1 and therefore when you install or move site on php 7 configured server it will show you blank screen, you will see above error when you enable the error reporting to 1 in index.php or in php.ini.

> Enable error reporting:
>
> ini_set('display_errors', 1);

That error comes because of syntax changes in php 7 which is deprecated, here is solution to this error.

**SOLUTIONS**

> You need to override app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php
>   Line no 555
>
> $out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback1;
>
> Replace or write override function for below line
>
> $out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();

This will fix your error for sure.

Comment: Looks like you've answered your own question, but there's a module written by inchoo that tries to fix all the PHP7 compatibility issues https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Comment: solution is to use search here, to find out that php7 upgrade was 6 months ago...

Comment: @MagenX what do you mean? There is no upgrade for M1 to go to PHP 7.

Comment: hm, i mean that lots of people already tried to use M1 with php7 long time ago, thats why we have this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74008/is-magento-ready-for-php-7  :)     php7 upgrade, not the M1 to php7 upgrade....

Comment: Yes, i just checked inchoo extension for php7, its interesting https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7/tree/master/app/code/local/Inchoo/PHP7

Comment: Clearing the cache after installing Inchoo_PHP7 resolved the issue.